# insert using sub-query and inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

i have these two tables.
The first is the **users_details** table

[image: Users_Details Table]

Second is the **users_posts** table.

[image: users_posts]

i want to fill the column **postedby_name** with **username** from the first column.

I tried a combination of inner join and sub-query but could not do it.

This is the code that i have now.

```
update users_posts
set users_posts.postedby_name = 
(select username from users_details inner join users_posts where
users_posts.postedby = users_details.id);
```

How to Accomplish this.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Update users_posts inner join users_details  
on users_posts.postedby = users_details.id 
set users_posts.postedby_name=users_details.username
```

Comment: No problem. I'd upvote your answer, but don't remember enough about `SQL` to know if it's correct.

Comment: @SteveP. its ok i can understand.

Comment: @Narendra it happen sometime its in your mind but it didnt come out.Your always welcome